# Copy and Paste an array of cells with information dependent on a lock cell (from a reference cell) with relative value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, locking

I am having the following problem:

**I have a list of items number and descriptions starting at A5 and going down, at B5 I have the total sold quantity over a year, C5 corresponds to sales price per unit and D5 to its COGS per unit.**

Further down, starting in cell A12 I have a specific item number and its description. I have then the quantity sold of this item each month (cells B13:D13) and underneath I want to have the sales quantity per month times the unit sales price of that item (that is in cells B14:D14).

To do so, from B14 I look up the item number and description in A12, in the list of items I mentioned before ($A$5:$D$7) in order to get the price for that item and then multiply it by that months sold quantity.

The problem with this approach is that when I drag that result along, over the following months, it stops searching the value at A12 and instead looks for the item value at B12, then C12 etc etc.

So in order to fix that I locked the value at A12 using the formula `'=B13*VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(Artikel)+ROWS(Artikel)-4;COLUMN(Artikel)+COLUMNS(Artikel)-4);TRUE);ItemSales;3;FALSE)`. Thanks to that, I am able to drag the result of the first month over the next months and to get a right result.

However, I would like to copy the table with the monthly results ( $B$13:$D$15 ) and paste it some rows bellows, and that the item referenced is not anymore the previous one at A12, but a new one let’s say in A26.

I achieve that with the formula k=VLOOKUP(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()));-2;-1;1;1);ItemSales;3;FALSE)*B27 but this formula doesn’t hold the item number and description value when dragged along, so I don’t get to combine them both

Any ideas how I can make it happen??

[image: Excel_problem_description]

Comment: Learn about relative and absolute referencing. Note that named ranges are always absolute.

Comment: Where are your named ranges "Artikel" and "ItemSales". Where do the data for Month2, Month3, etc come from.

Comment: Hi,  Artikel refers to $A$12:$D$15, ItemSales to $A$5:$D$7, and the quantity per month is manually introduced.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have designed two formulas for you. The first one is for column A. Enter it in A12 and copy down, 6 rows for each row in your `Item_Sales` range.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),6)=0,INDEX(Item_Sales,INT((ROW()-12)/6)+1,1),IFERROR(INDEX({"Total quantity","Total Sales","Total COGS"},MOD(ROW(),6)),""))
```

Note that the number 12, wherever it occurs in the formula refers to row 12, where your named range "Artikel" starts. It's the first row where the first item in "Item_Sales" must appear. The number 6 refers to the number of rows in one data set, essentially Rows(12:17) for the first set, Rows(18:23) for the second etc. Your row 16 is hidden, row 17 blank. If you want the formula to write anything there expand the array `{"Total quantity","Total Sales","Total COGS"}`

The other formula is for cell B13. From there you can copy it to B14:B15. You can also copy B13:B15 to B19 but in its present form the formula will throw an error in B16:B18.

```
=INDEX(Item_Sales,INT((ROW()-12)/6)+1,MOD(ROW(),6)+1)*IF(ISNUMBER(B12),B12,1)
```

Again, the meaning of numbers 12 and 6 is as explained above. You would need to modify them if your data or display format changes in the future.

For your better understanding, I used the INDEX function which takes a 2D range and extracts values from it based on coordinates. `INDEX(Item_Sales, 1, 2)` returns the value of the cell in the first row, second column of the range defined as "Item_Sales". Of course, these numbers can be calculated.

The other functions I use are INT() and MOD(). Int(5/6) returns 0, as does INT(1/6). This function can be used to locate the first row in a set the repeats every 6 rows. INT(13/6) returns 2, INT(19/6)=3. These calculations identify the row numbers in `Item_Sales` referenced in `Artikel`.

MOD returns the modulus of a division. `MOD(5, 6)` returns 5, `MOD(13,6)` returns 1. If there is no modulus the return is 0. With the help of this information you can repetitively count from 0 to 6 and restart with 0.

Comment: Fantastic. It is just simply elegant. The first formula is so neat, the second purely intelligent, it would have never crossed my mind to use the MOD formula in the way you did it, but yeah of course, logically. Thanks for yout time Variatus, for giving it a thought and helping out. Cheers!